# Overflow broken on responsive thumbnails with h1 overlay

Tags: html, css, thumbnails

I'm trying to get my thumbnails to span 50% of their containing DIV, with the height being automatic, and a h1 header on top. Right now the h1 header is determining the height of the containing DIV, so the full thumbnail image is not viewable unless you scroll down (scrollbars are not desired). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="featured">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/featured1.jpg" /></a>
    <h1><a href="#">Content for  class "featured" Goes Here</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="featured">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/featured2.jpg" /></a>
    <h1><a href="#">Content for  class "featured" Goes Here</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#content {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.featured {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
.featured img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.featured h1 {
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 32px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.featured>a{
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:0;
}
#content .featured:not(:hover) img {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.2);
    -moz-filter: brightness(0.2);
    -ms-filter: brightness(0.2);
    -o-filter: brightness(0.2);
    filter: brightness(0.2);
}
#content .featured:hover img {
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -moz-transition:all .4s;
    -ms-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition:all .4s;
    transition:all .4s;
}
```

How my thumbnails look now:
[image: problem]

And how I want my thumbnails to look:
[image: desired outcome]

Comment: Why dont you make the image as background and a semi transparent black div over it ?

Comment: I guess because I thought that since the images will be determined by WordPress featured images, that it would be easier to make them the actual image, versus a background. And, truthfully, I don't know how I would do that as a background... could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ?
http://jsfiddle.net/L8ttn0nb/

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #AB700C;
}

.wrapper > .child {
 width: 50%;
 height: 97%;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 float: left;
 display: table; 
}

.wrapper > .child > .content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 display: table-cell; 
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}

.wrapper > .child > .content:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.wrapper > .child > .content a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper > .child.left {
 background-image: url(images/featured1.jpg);
}

.wrapper > .child.right {
 background-image: url(images/featured2.jpg);
 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="child left">
  <div class="content">
   <h1>
    <a href="#">
     Content for  class "featured" Goes Here
    </a>
   </h1>
  </div>   
 </div>
 <div class="child right">
  <div class="content">
   <h1>
    <a href="#">
     Content for  class "featured" Goes Here
    </a>
   </h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way what is the font type that you are using ?

Comment: Fonts are Oswald and Open Sans

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I guess now I just wonder how I can pull the "featured image" SRC of each Wordpress post and use that as the background...?

Comment: I just deleted the `left` and `right` classes from the html and put the background into an inline style: `<div class="child" style="background:url(images/featured1.jpg); background-size: cover;">`
This should let me call in in Wordpress. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah. That is a solution :)